# Change or remove initial drag threshold for onPanStart or onPanUpdate in GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I'm not 100% sure this isn't an emulator-only issue.

It seems that when I try to detect a drag event in GestureDetector (onPanStart / onPanUpdate), onPanStart doesn't get called until the drag has already moved about 20 pixels. This is obviously intended to prevent confusion with onTap and other gestures.

However, I wonder where I can access or change this threshold value. I would like to assume any fingerdown/mousedown on this particular widget is a drag, and therefore does not need to move a certain distance before the drag is considered to have started. I tried to use Draggable, but I ran into the same issue (although I think the threshold was less)

It would be ideal to hook into the onTapDown event and then calculate the finger offset every frame from there until onTapUp, but there is no "onTapMove" event.

Thanks!

Comment: check [kTouchSlop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/kTouchSlop-constant.html)

Comment: Thanks pskink - that's handy. It looks like because this is top-level it means it will affect the whole application whereas I am looking for only a solution for one specific widget. But useful nonetheless to help me understand what's going on under the hood

Comment: what if you use Listener, Listener(onPointerMove: (opm) { print("onPointerMove .. ${opm.position}");}

Comment: @pskink kan kTouchSlop be edited? It's const

Comment: @MarwinLebensky I don't think so